# How to replace () with empty spacein notepad ++

Tags: replace, notepad++, space, braces

How to replace empty braces ( ) with empty space in notepad++.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Note pad++ do ctrl+h and then check 'extend' option

now 
find what ()
replace with    (empty space)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\(\)`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

You have to escape the parenthesis because they have special meaning in a regex